# How to Create a Custom Scrollbar in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, scrollbar, uwp-xaml, customscrollview

I need to create a custom Scrollbar in UWP ? But I can't find any clear logic to calculate Scrollbar thumb width and Position.
What I have tried ?

```
ThumbWidth=(VisibleLength/TotalLength)*ScrollRegionWidth;
ThumbPosition=(ScrollLeft/TotalLength)*ScrollRegionWidth;
```

where,

```
VisibleLength -> viewable area width  
TotalLength -> Total Content width  
ScrollRegionWidth -> Scrollbar width - (2 x ArrowWidth)  (or) Thumb Track width
ScrollLeft -> how much content scrolled !!
```

Is it correct ? I tried like this . But the scrollbar thumb won't goes to end of thumb track while my whole content is scrolled to end !

I need to create a custom Scrollbar and how to do it ? I need complete logic for thumb width and position .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to Create a Custom Scrollbar in UWP?

```
ThumbWidth=(VisibleLength/TotalLength)*ScrollRegionWidth;
```

Your first line is correct. and you could verify it with `VisibleLength = TotalLength`, then `ThumbWidth` will fill all the `ScrollRegion`.

```
ThumbPosition=(ScrollLeft/TotalLength)*ScrollRegionWidth;
```

But the second line looks not correct, Thumb's start position should be left top, the ScrollRegion should be (`ScrollRegionWidth` - `ThumbWidth`).

```
ThumbPosition=(ScrollLeft/TotalLength)*(ScrollRegionWidth-ThumbWidth);
```

Comment: How to calculate the step to be scrolled if 1px of thumb is moved ?

Comment: It's math problem,  `ScrollLeft = (ThumbPosition * TotalLength)/(ScrollRegionWidth-ThumbWidth)`

Comment: And i have one more question, if scrollable Content(Total Length) was high ,the scrollThumb width gets very small . So i'm going to set ScrollThumb Minimum width as 20 .In this case how to scroll content ?

Comment: Base on  this `ScrollLeft = (ThumbPosition * TotalLength)/(ScrollRegionWidth-ThumbWidth)`  if TotalLength more than threshold value, we could set ThumbWidth as fix value 20. it will not effect `ScrollLeft` value right?

Comment: ThumbPosition=(ScrollLeft/TotalLength)*ScrollRegionWidth --> actually this works fine except threshold case.
But ThumbPosition=(ScrollLeft/TotalLength)*(ScrollRegionWidth-ThumbWidth) won't work well and it scroll beyond the totalLength

Comment: how many length  beyond the ScrollRegionWidth? can you share a screenshot ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241892/discussion-between-premkumar-shanmugam-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Comment: so the distance from 255 to 273 equal thumb's width ?

Comment: ThumbWidth calculation was Right. ThumbPosition should be ThumbPosition=(ScrollLeft/TotalLength)*(ScrollRegionWidth-(ThumbWidth-ActualThumbWidth)).
We need to cache the ActualThumbWidth for the case to maintain the minimum ThumbWidth. It works perfect for me.